# A fatal mistake

Tags: riddle

> - You did well and you are full of me, but you might have to swallow me to keep on going.
> - Don't get all green over me, just take it and be done with it.
> - You can scream all you want but without the anger I give you, you'll just look silly.
> - If you can't decide between a pie and a cake, just use me and your problem will be gone.
> - Don't look at me like I'm creepy, you're alive thanks to me!
> - What's so wrong with always watching TV, can't you just let me be?
> - Generosity is just silly, just give me your candy!
> - I am the sum of all above me. Don't underestimate me for a fatal mistake that might be.

Who am I?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are talking about the

> Seven deadly sins

You did well and you are full of me, but you might have to swallow me to keep on going.

> **Pride**. You are proud after an achievement. However, when you make a mistake, you have to swallow your pride.

Don't get all green over me, just take it and be done with it.

> **Envy**. Refers to the phrase, green with envy.

You can scream all you want but without the anger I give you, you'll just look silly.

> **Wrath**. Often characterized by anger and screaming, but can even be expressed by its absence through throwing a fit.

If you can't decide between a pie and a cake, just use me and your problem will be gone.

> **Gluttony**. A glutton wants to eat anything and everything.

Don't look at me like I'm creepy, you're alive thanks to me!

> **Lust**. Lustful looks are often considered creepy by the recipient of them. But lust is the reason that leads to procreation and our birth.

What's so wrong with always watching TV, can't you just let me be?

> **Sloth**. Sitting on a couch and watching TV is a common form of laziness.

Generosity is just silly, just give me your candy!

> **Greed**. The opposite of generosity, and wanting what others have.

To explain the last line,

I am the sum of all above me. Don't underestimate me for a fatal mistake that might be.

> Together these are known as the Seven Deadly (fatal) Sins (mistake).

Comment: That was fast. Good job!

Answer (score 8):

You did well and you are full of me, but you might have to swallow me to keep on going.

> **Pride**
>  - Do something great & you are full of pride! But you have to get it out of your head & keep your feet on ground!

Don't get all green over me, just take it and be done with it.

> **Envy**
>  - 'Getting green with envy' is a phrase, to describe that you are envious of someone & it have taken over you. To get out of that situation you have to accept everything as it is & move on.

You can scream all you want but without the anger I give you, you'll just look silly.

> **Wrath**
>  - Sometime getting angry is good. If you are in such situation & can't express you anger, it'll make you miserable & affect everything. Anger gives you a way out!

If you can't decide between a pie and a cake, just use me and your problem will be gone.

> **Gluttony**
>  - Why choose when I can eat both!
>  - (Buurrrppp... oops, sorry)

Don't look at me like I'm creepy, you're alive thanks to me!

> **Lust**
>  - Lust is a taboo subject but sort of necessary to reproduction & survival of species!

What's so wrong with always watching TV, can't you just let me be?

> **Sloth**
>  - Why this is a wrong? Sometime I just wan't to lie around & forgot everything else

Generosity is just silly, just give me your candy!

> **Greed**
>  - Greedy person consider generosity as a silly concept, they'll grab everything they set eye on!

---

All these points refers to:

> Seven Sins

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: @Deusovi isn't it self explanatory?

Comment: @Sikorski: Not necessarily - it doesn't explain *how* the clues match up to the words.

Comment: @Deusovi I think it is self-explanatory! But will edit it once I reach a desktop, thats pretty hard to do on app :)

Comment: Good job! I know you found it all by yourself, but CodeNewbie posted his answer like 10 seconds before.

Comment: @stackreader yes that true, but edited the answer anyway to explain my points!